# Why is this query even working?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I've noticed a query that runs fine in my code but it's missing a where clause.

Why is it even working, is it a bug or a special scenario where a rule's interpretation gets tricky?

```
SELECT
    C.Id
    , C.Name
    , C.Qualifying
    , CI.PlaceG
    , CI.PlaceN
    , CI.Hcp
    , CI.NewHcp
FROM dbo.Competitions AS C
INNER JOIN dbo.CompInscription AS CI ON (
    CI.idcomp = C.id
)
AND C.archived = 1
AND CI.idmembre = 11227
AND CI.placeg IS NOT NULL
AND CI.placen IS NOT NULL
AND CI.Status IN (0, 8)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it run? The AND's belong to the INNER JOIN. It's all valid, where's the confusion?

Comment: Ok, I'm used to use parenthesis to have more readable code where ON clauses occur, but it doesn't mean the ON clauses actually end on the closing parenthesis if the following code is AND/OR. Thank for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NB has pointed out, what is happening here is that your conditionals are being applied to the JOIN rather than in a WHERE clause.

This *is* perfectly valid SQL but it's not seen much and is probably why it looks odd. If you replace the first AND with a WHERE you should get the same result.

Comment: You're right it wouldn't; conditionals in the JOIN are more usually seen in OUTER joins.